# Como Puxar um dado do mesmo campo?

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Fala pessoal, sei que pode ser boba a minha pergunta...
Mas como posso puxar os dados de um campo só no SQL.
É que na verdade eu estou montando um relatório dos produtos da empresa... Existem produtos que a unidade dele valor '1' mas ele quando é vendido em Caixa por exemplo, torna-se '0.98', entendeu? Eu queria fazer um seguinte, Tem um produto que a Unidade vale '1' e ele sendo vendido por caixa também vale '1', então eu ignoro... Porém tem um produto que o valor da unidade dele é '1' porém ele vendido em 'PT' ou 'CX' (Dependendo do produto) o valor dele desce para '0.98' então eu pego este produto 0.98 + os valores da Unidade que é '1' e se tiver mais Unidade de venda como PT ou DP (pacote e display) pega tudo também, entendeu? Já fiz coisa mais complexa que isso, mas minha cabeça bugou totalmente, desde ontem pensando e nada. obrigado.
Meu Código ficou assim:

`SELECT 
produto.cd_prod,
produto.descricao,
unid_prod.qtde_unid,
unid_prod.fator_preco,
unid_vda
FROM 
produto,
unid_prod
WHERE
unid_prod.cd_prod = produto.cd_prod
AND unid_prod.fator_preco = '0.9800'`

Só que neste caso a query só puxa 0.9800 e ignora o resto das Unidades de venda e eu queria que se fosse 0.9800 ele trouxesse as outras unidades de medida junto.
Sou Novo aqui, mas desde já agradeço.

Comment: fator_preco é um campo do tipo decimal ou varchar?

Comment: Você quer determinar uma busca pelo valor de um campo? Se sim, poderá retornar outros campos além do campo buscado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se `fator_preco` for do tipo VARCHAR use:

```
SELECT fator_preco FROM Tabela WHERE fator_preco LIKE '0.9800%';
```

`0.9800%` significa que você quer strings que começam com 0.9800, o `%` digamos que significa "restante".

Agora se `fator_preco` for do tipo DECIMAL, eu faria assim:

```
SELECT fator_preco FROM Tabela  WHERE CAST(fator_preco AS CHAR) LIKE '0.9800%'
```

Nesse caso você está utilizando o LIKE como no outro exemplo, porém fazendo um CAST no valor, convertendo de DECIMAL para VARCHAR.

Já teste aqui e funcionou perfeitamente, qualquer duvida só comentar !

Answer (score 0):

O caminho feio seria converter pra string e fazer um like... o caminho correto seria multiplicar o valor por 10000 e verificar se a parte inteira é 9800.

Comment: Isso é gambiarra

Comment: @Alexandro Carneiro Seria interessante colocar a query montada.